# Swift Keychain Status -50

Tags: swift, keychain

I am trying to use the keychain in swift to save a password, but when I try to call my save method it returns a status of -50.

Here is my function:

```
 class func save(key: String, data: String) -> OSStatus {
        let query = [
            kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
            kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
            kSecValueData as String   : data ]

        SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

        return SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
    }

 class func load(key: String) -> String? {
        let query = [
            kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
            kSecReturnData as String  : kCFBooleanTrue!,
            kSecMatchLimit as String  : kSecMatchLimitOne ] as [String : Any]

        var dataTypeRef: AnyObject? = nil

        let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &dataTypeRef)

        if status == noErr {
            return dataTypeRef as! String?
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

And then my attempt to call these function:

```
let status = KeyChain.save(key: "Ufde", data: "Eli")
                    print("status: ", status)
                    let receivedData = KeyChain.load(key: "Ufde") 
                        print(receivedData)
```

This is my first time attempting to use the keychain so I'm sorry if there's something really obvious I'm doing wrong here/

Comment: I'm not too sure, but are you sure it's `-5` not `-50`? I've got a hunch that the SecItemDelete is failing you, and, as far as I know, the `kSecAttrAccount` for a generic password is not unique. Another thing I noticed, on your save you say `kSecClassGenericPassword as String`, omit that `as String`. One final thing I'd like to point out is that the `kSecValueData` expects `Data` or for that matter `CFData`. Try converting your `String` first, before saving

Answer (score 0):

You are storing password as a string inside keychain. Convert password string into data

```
class func save(key: String, password: String) -> OSStatus {
 let data = password.data(using: .utf8)!
 let query = [
     kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
     kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
     kSecValueData as String   : data]
     SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
     return SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
}
```